# Printing info from executable pdfinfo in python

Tags: python, subprocess, pdftotext

```
path1 = "C:/Users/Gebruiker/PycharmProjects/pdf_processor/Files/pdf_files/"
pdffname = "testfile2.pdf"

file_info = subprocess.Popen(['pdfinfo', '-meta',
os.path.join(path1, pdffname)])
```

So I need to find out how many pages this pdf has. If I call the function in cmd it works fine. But how do I extract the data from the -meta command? The function returns no errors. The file_info variable is of type .

And supposedly the data from the -meta command is in xml format. But there is no option to extract an xml file anywhere. And it does not even print anything :/ . Completely lost here.

edit:

I actually made it work like this:

```
pdf_info = subprocess.Popen(['pdfinfo', '-meta',
os.path.join(path1, pdfname)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = pdf_info.stdout.read()

with open(os.path.join(path3, 'pdf_info.xml'), 'wb') as file:
    file.write(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever heard of PyPdf, you might have a solid option there.

```
import pyPdf
reader = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open("foo.pdf"))
print reader.getNumPages()
```

This should do what you are looking for

Comment: aah much easier. Thanks.

Comment: I get this error:

PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. It may not be read correctly. [pdf.py:1079]

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123, look at the requirements for the OPEN command.  It sounds like you may need something akin to:  open("foo.pdf", "b") wherein the second param is a file flag.  Feel free to google search for a flag which might be useful to you.

Comment: yeah this works:

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path1, pdfname), 'rb'))
print(reader.getNumPages())